# How do I write in typescript that I can combine function arguments at will and get hints about their type

Tags: typescript

How to DEFINE a function that takes 4 arguments (one required, three optional), can combine the arguments at will, and can be prompted for the corresponding type

```
function name （ url,params:type ）{}
function name （ url,params:type,config:ConfigType ）{}
function name （ url,params:type,config:ConfigType,option:OptionType ）{}
```

```
name('http',{params}) ||
name('http',{config})  || 
name('http',{option })   ||
name('http',{params}, {option }) ||
name('http',{config}, {option }) ||
name('http',{params}, {config})
```

What I can think of so far is overloading functions, but there are too many parameters to combine. Is there a better solution

Answer (score 0):

Considering that type parameters are the same in this variadic function, function overloads are not required, the parameters can be made optional:

```
function name (url: string, params?: Type, config?: SomeType, option?: AnotherType）{...}
```

It's often impractical to rely on optional parameters because this requires to maintain their order and requires to use IDE hints for correct parameter values. Since named arguments are missing in JavaScript, in this case it's more practical to use a single parameters object with optional keys, with the help of destructuring and object literal shorthands:

```
function name (
  { url, params, config, option }: {
    url: string,
    params?: Type,
    config?: SomeType,
    option?: AnotherType
  }
）{...}
```

Which is called like:

```
name({ url: 'http', params, config })
```

Comment: I may have a problem with the description, the types are inconsistent

Comment: Why is this a problem? You'd write ConfigType instead of Type for a param with respective type

Comment: I have edited the question again and look forward to your help

Comment: params?: Type,
    config?: Type,
    option?: Type     The types are not the same, there are three different types

Comment: I updated the post. You'll naturally have problems with variable naming like in another answer, since you already used all words that are suitable for that - params, config, option. With destructuring you may not need to give this object a specific name

Comment: I understand what you mean, whether you can do this by overloading functions

Comment: The way these params are typed doesn't change the way it works. You can do this by overloading functions, but you'd need to parse args. Basically the implementation is `function name (...args）{}` and there's a bunch of ifs based on args.length. Just results in fragile and verbose code for the same purpose.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248508/discussion-between-hn-ja-and-estus-flask).

Comment: Sorry, I don't use discussions on SO, they are broken. You would need to list all possible param combos above the implementation this way like `function name （ url: string , option:OptionType);` (semicolon, not brackets). See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads . You asked for a better solution. The better solution is what's suggested in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
type Params = {
 type?: /* ... */;
 config?: /* ... */;
 options?: /* ... */; 
}

function name (url: string, params?: Params ）{
  // ...
}
```

The `params` are optional, and so are its fields.
So you can call your function like:

```
name('http',{params})
name('http',{config})
name('http',{option})
name('http',{params, option})
name('http',{config, option})
name('http',{config, params})
name('http',{})
name('http')
```

Comment: I have thought of this scheme, but he needs to nest one more layer of objects, can there be another scheme